Is $\vdash_{GL} \square H \Rightarrow \vdash_{GL} H$ wrong in the modal provability logic GL?
I am currently reading about Gödel's second incompleteness theorem in Rautenberg's Einführung in die Mathematische Logik (see A Concise Introduction to Mathematical Logic p. 289 for an English version of the book) and he introduces a modal provability logic $G$ (I assume it is the same as $GL$, but they restrict the semantics to only finite partial orderings which shouldn't make a difference I guess). Sadly this is the last chapter and the author doesn't give proofs anymore. Now I tried to prove something and I would need the statement from the title to do that. But i don't see any way to prove that syntactically. However I found the following meta-theoretic proof:

Let $H$ be a formula from the language of $GL$ and assume $\vdash_{GL} \square H$

By Solovay's theorem we get that $\vdash_{PA} \square H^\iota$ for all substitutions $\iota \in \mathcal{L}_{PA}^0$.

By $\omega$-consistency of $PA$ we get $\vdash_{PA} H^\iota$ for all substitutions ι.

By applying Solovay's theorem again we get $\vdash_{GL} H$


I can also give an intuitive proof by using the semantics of $GL$ (but it isn't detailed enough to be sound): Assume $H$ is false in some world $w$ of some model of $GL$. Then we can construct a new model by adding a world $w'$ where the variables have arbitrary values and that is connected to $w$ and all its successors and the truth value of every formula is evaluated accordingly. Then $\square H$ must be false in $w'$ and thus in $GL$.
But I can not prove that statement using the rules and axioms of $GL$ syntactically. I don't mean $\vdash_{GL} \square H \rightarrow H$, which is only true for valid $H$ and thus not always valid. But this doesn't necessarily contradict the meta-theoretic statement. What I mean is, assuming $\vdash_{GL} \square H$ how can we derive $\vdash_{GL} H$ only by using the rules and axioms of $GL$, should my proof above be valid? And if it is not, where does it go wrong?

It doesn't really make sense to say you assume the proof to be false but you can't see what the problem is. Try reviewing each step of the proof and asking yourself if you really understand what is happening. Ask yourself if every step is fully justified, and if one of them isn't, why not. Review the statement of Solovay's theorem and its proof. Finally, don't ask ChatGPT if a certain proposition is right or is wrong, because it probably doesn't know enough to give a factually correct answer.

@cpiegore thx for the feedback, i rephrased the question. And of course i don't trust ChatGPT, that's why i am posting here. But if ChatGPT repeatedly claims it is wrong and i can't find the statement anywhere it is a red flag for me and i would rather have my proof checked by someone.

In your first paragraph you say "in that book they introduce a modal provability logic $G$." What specific book are you referring to? Who is the author? Do you have any reason to believe that they don't give proofs anymore?

It is a German book "Einführung in die Mathematische Logik" by Wolfgang Rautenberg. And he doesn't prove the claim that i want to prove. Especially that claim leads me to conclude, that my proof must be wrong and i just would like to know why. The claim is the following: Let $GS$ be the closure of $G \cup {\square p \rightarrow p}$ under substitution and MP. Then $H \in GS \iff \mathcal{N} \vDash H^\iota$ for all $\iota$. This means, that if there is one $H$ true under $\mathcal{N}$ but not under some non-standard model, my proof in the post must be wrong. But i don't see the error.

@MarvinBergmann could you add to the question the page reference of the part you've brought up in the English or German edition?

@Tankut Beygu Ah thank you very much, for linking the book! The pages i am struggling with are 287-289, but the statement i have referenced specifically is on page 289 Thm. 5.4 and also the paragraph following it.

@MarvinBergmann Solovay's construction admits $\Sigma_{1}$-soundness, i.e., $\omega\vDash\mathsf{Prov}(\ulcorner\phi\urcorner)\implies\omega\vDash\phi$ where $\phi\in\Sigma_{1}$. I retract my answer for now to review it.

@TankutBeygu regarding your comment from the deleted comment: The author does introduce the bimodal logic in chapter 7.5, however this is not the definition he uses in the mentioned chapter. I will probably ask the question regarding the numerals in a separate post, since that is also something that i want to understand. If you want, you could have a look at page 271, there it is proven, that at least for $PA$ my argument should hold and the problem must be at in another step than 3.

It is true that $\vdash_{\mathrm{GL}}\square\varphi$ implies $\vdash_{\mathrm{GL}}\varphi$. This property also holds for many of the other standard modal logics. It is called the Reflection Rule here, but I'm not sure that's a standard name. Being the converse of the Necessitation Rule, it seems natural enough, so I'd be surprised if it doesn't appear in the literature somewhere. Maybe someone more expert in modal logic than me can point to a reference.
The proof you gave using Solovay's theorem looks correct to me. Even better (and far more elementary) is your semantic proof using Kripke models. You wrote that the semantic proof isn't detailed enough to be sound, but it's essentially complete. All that's missing is the easy verification that $H$ is still false at world $w$ in the new frame where you've adjoined the new world $w'$.
I don't know how to give a purely syntactic proof that the Reflection Rule is admissible in $\mathrm{GL}$.
In the comments, you wrote:

The claim is the following: Let $\mathrm{GS}$ be the closure of $\mathrm{G[L]}\cup \{\square p\to p\}$ under substitution and $\mathrm{MP}$. Then $H\in \mathrm{GS}\iff \mathcal{N}\models H^\iota$ for all [insertions] $\iota$. This means, that if there is one $H$ true under $\mathcal{N}$ but not under some non-standard model, my proof in the post must be wrong.

I assume $\mathcal{N}$ is $\mathbb{N}$, the standard natural numbers. I'm not sure I follow your reasoning here, but I guess it's the following: If the Reflection Rule is admissible in $\mathrm{GL}$, then we don't get anything new by applying $\mathrm{MP}$ to an instance of $\square p\to p$. Well, you're right about that. But not everything in $\mathrm{GS}$ is of this form! For example, $\mathrm{GS}$ contains $\square P\to P$, and this sentence is not provable in $\mathrm{GL}$. In other words, for every insertion $\iota$, $\mathbb{N}\models (\square P\to P)^\iota$, but this is not true across all models of $\mathsf{PA}$.

thank you very much! Yeah i got confused about the direction of my argument in the comments.
